# How do I block/redirect '?post_type=cpt_name' urls?

Tags: custom-post-types

With CPTs, I want to block access at query string urls of '?post_type=cpt_name' and have single items available only at regular urls (/cpt_name/).

An example of my current register_cpt code is:

```
function channel_cpt() {

$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Channels', 'post type general name' ),
'singular_name'=> _x( 'Channel', 'post type singular name' ),
'menu_name'=> __( 'Channels' ),
'add_new' => __( 'Add new' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new Channel' ),
'all_items' => __( 'View all' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Channel' ),
'new_item' => __( 'Channel' ),
'view_item' => __( 'View Channel' ), //
'search_items' => __( 'Search Channels' ),
'not_found' => __( 'No Channels found.' ),
'not_found_in_trash'=> __( 'No Channels found in trash.' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Channel' )
);

$args = array(

'label' => __('Channel'),
'description' => __( 'Geographic channels' ),
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => false,
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'menu_position' => 20,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-megaphone',
'public' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'programs/channels', 'with_front' => false ),
'supports' => $supports = array(
 'excerpt',
 'page-attributes',
 'post-formats',
 'revisions',
),
'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ),
);

register_post_type( 'channel', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'channel_cpt', 0);
```

Comment: Are the query strings being given by default?  Or are you just worried about people typing them in?

Comment: @socki03 ... Thanks. It's 'typing-in' that I want to control.

Comment: Did you declare a 'has-archive' element? Could you post your register_post_type code?

Comment: @socki03 ... Code now added to question. Archives are 'off' because I have 'pseudo-archives'' using a page with an appropriate query.

Comment: And I assume you've already tried turning the 'publicly_queryable' variable to false, and you didn't like the results, right?

Comment: @socki03 ... yes, I initially mistakenly thought it would block query string urls, but it seems to prevent all front-end access. I can't see an option other than to use a rewrite function or in .htaccess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48891/discussion-between-socki03-and-gulliver).